# pg_trgm behaves differently on Ubuntu and Mac OS X

Tags: macos, postgresql, ubuntu

I am using `pg_trgm` to perform fuzzy string match where characters can be Chinese. Strangely, on my Ubuntu server, everything is fine, as following:

```
SELECT show_trgm('原作者');
> {0xa09182,0xcdfdbb,0x183afe,leD}
```

However, on my Mac, it does not work:

```
SELECT show_trgm('原作者');
> {}
```

I guess it is due to some strange encoding staff, but I examined all settings that I can possibly imagine, including:

```
SHOW SERVER_VERSION;
SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;
SHOW LC_COLLATE;
SHOW LC_CTYPE;
```

Where on Ubuntu it shows:

```
9.5.1
UTF8
en_US.UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8
```

and on Mac it shows:

```
9.5.3
UTF8
en_US.UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8
```

Also, the `pg_trgm` versions are both 1.1, according to `SELECT * FROM pg_extension`.

Could anyone help me to find why the `pg_trgm` not works on Unicode on my Mac?

Comment: You found any solutions to this? Having the same problem.

Comment: I have same problem, do you like share your solution?

Comment: Same here, postgresql installed through homebrew, both with postgres 12.2 and 11.7.

Comment: Did you try https://www.postgresql-archive.org/pg-trgm-not-recognizing-Chinese-characters-in-macOS-td6037655.html ?

Comment: Seems to be a CTYPE issue like described @ https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/0A0622C3-C778-4C6A-9345-0A6D81929BCF%40phlo.org.

Comment: Can you try using `zh_CN.UTF-8`?

Comment: Probably adding `E` won't change anything, but give it a try: `SELECT show_trgm(E'原作者');`

Answer (score 1):

Reason for this is that `pg_trgm` depends on `libc` (system library shipped with OS) routines for classifying which characters are alphabetic and which aren't and this is (unfortunately) different between OSes. Apple Mac OS X is known for interpreting UTF-8 different way than other Unix/Unix-like systems. Character classification is different per-locale and is driven by category `LC_CTYPE` (and envvar of same name).

Check output of `postgres=# \l` and you should see `Ctype` column which tells you how characters are classified in your database.

- If this is `C` (seen that on Apple MacOS X before) try to create database again specifying `CREATE DATABASE foo ... LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"`
- If it is already `en_US.UTF-8` it is very likely MacOS X doesn't classify UTF-8 Chinese characters as alphabetic in this locale (not surprising). Try `LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"` instead and that should work.

Answer (score 1):

In macOS, this is the issue of character encoding. Based on the language you have to explicitly flag the encoding type. default en_US.UTF-8 will definitely don't work. so:

```
Chinese : LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
```

likewise, locale should be changed accordingly to the language. Although, there is no point of encode/decode Chinese in US English

You can create db:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb WITH ENCODING='UTF8' LC_CTYPE='zh_CN.UTF-8' LC_COLLATE='zh_CN.UTF-8' OWNER=postgres TEMPLATE=template0 CONNECTION LIMIT=-1;
```